# r: pass a variable name as a string

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to produce many histograms with a similar format, and so **I want to make the specific graph code into a function**. my function is :

```
DistribGraph <- function(VectorToGraph, VarName = "var", title,
                         limit_lo = 50, limit_hi = 150, bin_width = 5, tik_width = 10) {
  
  data <- data.frame(VarName = VectorToGraph)
  
  graph <- ggplot(data) +
    aes(x = VarName) +
    ggtitle(title) + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(limit_lo, limit_hi, tik_width), 
                       limits = c(limit_lo, limit_hi)) +
    geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(density)),
                   binwidth = bin_width, 
                   fill = "#69b3a2", 
                   boundary = limit_lo,
                   color = "#e9ecef",  
                   alpha = 0.9) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold")) +  
    stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = mean(VectorToGraph), 
                                           sd = sd(VectorToGraph)))
  
  return(graph)
}
```

And calling it, for example,

```
DistribGraph(mtcars$mpg, "mpg", "mpg - Histogram", 10, 35, 1, 5)
```

produces the desired graph, almost perfectly. **The only problem is the  x axis name which is "VarName", instead of "mpg"**.

[image: histogram with incorrect x axis name]

I suspect that the problem is either in `data.frame(VarName = VectorToGraph)` or in `aes(x = VarName)`, in that R takes the name of the variable instead of the content of the variable...

The question: **how can I pass a variable name as a string, instead of the variable containing the string?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not pass the label name so far. Just add `labs(x=VarName)+` and you will get your desired output:

```
DistribGraph <- function(VectorToGraph, VarName = "var", title,
                         limit_lo = 50, limit_hi = 150, bin_width = 5, tik_width = 10) {
  
  data <- data.frame(VarName = VectorToGraph)
  
  graph <- ggplot(data) +
    aes(x = VarName) +
    ggtitle(title) + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(limit_lo, limit_hi, tik_width), 
                       limits = c(limit_lo, limit_hi)) +
    geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(density), x = VarName),
                   binwidth = bin_width, 
                   fill = "#69b3a2", 
                   boundary = limit_lo,
                   color = "#e9ecef",  
                   alpha = 0.9) +
    labs(x=VarName)+
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold")) +  
    stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = mean(VectorToGraph), 
                                           sd = sd(VectorToGraph)))
  
  return(graph)
}

DistribGraph(mtcars$mpg, "mpg", "mpg - Histogram", 10, 35, 1, 5)
```

[image]